# Mocked JPA repository bean is not returning assigned value from a mocked method call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito, spring-test

I have a interface `CalculatorService` whose implementation contains business logic.

Interface:

```java
public interface CalculatorService {
    
    LoanWeb calculateSimpleLoan(LoanWeb loanWeb) throws Exception;
   
}
```

Implementation:

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CalculatorServiceImpl implements CalculatorService {

    private final LoanRepository loanRepository; //this extends JpaRepository
    private final PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;
    private final CalculatorUtility calculatorUtility;
    private final LoanInfoRepository loanInfoRepository;

    @Override
    public LoanWeb calculateSimpleLoan(LoanWeb loanWeb) throws Exception {

        //validation
        if (loanWeb.getLoanTerm() == null || loanWeb.getLoanTerm() <= 0) throw new LeanPayException(ErrorCode.INVALID_INTEGER_ERROR.code, List.of("loanTerm"));
    

        var payments = someCalculation();

        Loan loan = loanRepository.findFirstByAmountAndRateAndPaymentsAndFrequency
                (loanWeb.getLoanAmount(), loanWeb.getInterestRate(), payments, Frequency.MONTHLY); //loan is null???!!!


        if (loan != null) return LoanWeb.builder() //this is false, I need it to be true!
                .monthlyPayment(loan.getPmt())
                .totalInterestPaid(loan.getLoanInfos().stream().mapToDouble(LoanInfo::getInterest).sum()).build();

    }
}
```

JpaRepository:

```java
@Repository
public interface LoanRepository extends JpaRepository<Loan, Long> {

    Loan findFirstByAmountAndRateAndPaymentsAndFrequency(Double amount, Double rate, Integer payments, Frequency frequency);
}
```

Test class:

It looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled: false", "logging.level.com.package.calculator: OFF"},
        classes= {ObjectMapper.class, CalculatorServiceImpl.class, LoanRepository.class})
public class CalculatorServiceTest  {

    @Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Autowired
    private CalculatorService calculatorService;

    @MockBean(classes = LoanRepository.class) private LoanRepository loanRepository;
    @MockBean private PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;
    @MockBean private CalculatorUtility calculatorUtility;
    @MockBean private LoanInfoRepository loanInfoRepository;
    @MockBean private TestService testService;

    private Loan loan1; //this is not null, it is correctly loaded from a file.


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException{
        String jsonString =
                IOUtils.toString(
                        Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/json/PreExistingLoan.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        this.loan1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Loan.class);
    }

    @Test
    void calculateSimpleLoanWithPreExistingLoan() throws LeanPayException  {
    Mockito.doReturn(this.loan1).when(loanRepository).findFirstByAmountAndRateAndPaymentsAndFrequency( ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(),
                ArgumentMatchers.anyInt(), ArgumentMatchers.any(Frequency.class));

        LoanWeb result = this.calculatorService.calculateSimpleLoan(LoanWeb.builder().loanTerm(10).simpleLoanTerm(SimpleLoanTerm.MONTH).build());

        Assertions.assertEquals(result.getTotalInterestPaid(), 10);
        Assertions.assertEquals(result.getMonthlyPayment(), 107.0);
    }
}
```

Application context is brought up, test runs, but mocked repo method call returns null in service. Where am I wrong? I tried million things, this is code from beginning, don't have any ideas.

Comment: Any chance null is passed as one of arguments of your repository method?

Comment: Edit, I see what you mean. In my test method at this.calculatorService.calculateSimpleLoan(LoanWeb.builder()...) needs to have non null value. And then repository returned non-null values as I wanted! Thank you! You can set your comment in the answer and I will mark it as correct. Completely missed that! I don't know why is such behaviour of Mockito for jpa repo? I mean, I mocked the repo call with ArgumentMatchers, didn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble()](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyDouble()) matches any double (primitive) or **non-null** Double (boxed) value.

If you happen to pass a null value, it won't be matched.

You have a couple of options:

- use `ArgumentMatchers.any()` which matches anything, including nulls
- use `ArgumentMatchers.eq(null)` on the argument where the null is passed
- modify your test to pass a non-null value